# How to correct a phase error of the form $e^{ix}$

Tags: error-correction

Is there a method to correct an error of the form of $e^{ix}$, acted on a two-qubit state without knowing the nature (the value of x) of the error?

For example,
$$\alpha|00\rangle +\beta|01\rangle+\gamma|10\rangle+e^{ix}\delta|11\rangle.$$

Also, can I rephrase the above question to:

Is there a method to correct an error that results an orthogonal state to deform into a non-orthogonal state?

Comment: Could you use more math to describe the error? Does it affect a single amplitude, multiple amplitudes? What approaches can we use to correct it? (etc. etc)

Comment: Added. My question is in a general sense, is there any existing method or code to correct such type of errors or do errors like this even considered/exist? Is it safe to say: A phase shift will convert a previously orthogonal state to a non-orthogonal state, which will ultimately affect the probability of the outcome?

Comment: Ooh okay, so first the phase shift will not have an impact on the probability, as |e^{ix} \delta|^2 = |e^{ix}|^2 |\delta|^2 = |\delta|^2. To correct for such an error, you could use a controlled Rz rotation